# Mathematical induction divisibility

Tags: induction, divisibility

I am currently looking through this problem in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYy_rXKJDtk

The video asks: Prove that 4^k-1 is always a multiple of 3 for n = 1,2,3...

Looks like an induction question, the teacher in this video solves it like this
4^k  - 1 = 3P
4^(k+1) - 1 = 3Q
Solve for LHS
4^(k+1) - 1
4^k - 1 + 3*(4^k)

HOW did he get this step??

the next steps is 
3P + 3*(4^K)
3(P + 4^K)
I understand this step though.